# Specifiying nesting namespaces with prefixlist for XML::CanonicalizeXML

Tags: xml, perl

I'm (or rather, the [`Net::SAML2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SAML2) library I'm using is) trying to canonicalize XML and getting namespace errors.  I have the impression this is a matter of setting the prefixlist correctly, but I have no idea what format that is supposed to be in.  (`Net::SAML2` seems to be attempting to generate a list but coming up empty.)  Sample code:

```
use XML::CanonicalizeXML;

my $xml = '<saml:Assertion xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0" ID="pfx894bbcab-a4d3-7694-5b56-26dc207e3479" IssueInstant="2014-09-12T01:51:30Z"><saml:Issuer>http://example.com/metadata</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">bob@example.com</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-12T01:54:30Z" Recipient="{recipient}" InResponseTo="3e19c9272c04531d0c01643749e9dfda" /></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-09-12T01:48:30Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-12T01:54:30Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>{audience}</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-09-12T01:51:29Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2014-09-13T01:51:30Z" SessionIndex="_59f97890-1bff-0132-6393-782bcb56fcaa"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Attribute Name="first_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Billy</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion>';
my $xpath = '<XPath>(//. | //@* | //namespace::*)</XPath>';
my $prefixlist = '';
my $canon = XML::CanonicalizeXML::canonicalize($xml,$xpath,$prefixlist,1,0);
```

produces these warnings:

```
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Assertion is not defined
ID="pfx894bbcab-a4d3-7694-5b56-26dc207e3479" IssueInstant="2014-09-12T01:51:30Z"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Issuer is not defined
ab-a4d3-7694-5b56-26dc207e3479" IssueInstant="2014-09-12T01:51:30Z"><saml:Issuer
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Subject is not defined
2T01:51:30Z"><saml:Issuer>http://example.com/metadata</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on NameID is not defined
ubject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on SubjectConfirmation is not defined
:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on SubjectConfirmationData is not defined
54:30Z" Recipient="{recipient}" InResponseTo="3e19c9272c04531d0c01643749e9dfda" 
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Conditions is not defined
:Conditions NotBefore="2014-09-12T01:48:30Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-12T01:54:30Z"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AudienceRestriction is not defined
4-09-12T01:48:30Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-12T01:54:30Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Audience is not defined
0Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-09-12T01:54:30Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AuthnStatement is not defined
fter="2014-09-13T01:51:30Z" SessionIndex="_59f97890-1bff-0132-6393-782bcb56fcaa"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AuthnContext is not defined
:51:30Z" SessionIndex="_59f97890-1bff-0132-6393-782bcb56fcaa"><saml:AuthnContext
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AuthnContextClassRef is not defined
97890-1bff-0132-6393-782bcb56fcaa"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AttributeStatement is not defined
ntextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement><saml:AttributeStatement
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on Attribute is not defined
Name="first_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix saml on AttributeValue is not defined
Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                                               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing

```
xmlns:saml="..."
```

The value? Looks like

```
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
```

or

```
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
```

On the basis of the multitude of instances of `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:...` in the document, it's obviously the latter.

Comment: Yes, the larger document this is a snippet of has that; but I need just this snippet canonicalized.  There appears to be a way to tell the canonicalizer about namespaces declared in an outer scope, but I don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: There is a way to specify it, and I showed what it was. XML documents are self-contained. There is no larger scope. I'm not quite sure what the third arg is, but it's expected to be a list of comma-separated *prefixes* (passed to [`xmlC14NExecute`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-c14n.html#xmlC14NExecute)) which surely used to *control output*, not define namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Sig::OO#Working-with-Net::SAML2

The example from the pod shows how to resolve this:

```
  use Net::SAML2::Protocol::Assertion;
    use XML::Sig::OO;
    use MIME::Base64;

    # Lets assume we have a post binding response
    my $saml_response=.....

    my $xml=decode_base64($saml_response);

    my $v=XML::Sig::OO->new(xml=>$xml,cacert=>'idp_cert.pem');
    my $result=$v->validate;
    die $result unless $result;

    # we can now use the asertion knowing it was from our idp
    my $assertion=Net::SAML2::Protocol::Assertion->new_from_xml(xml=>$xml)
```

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I was doing, but Net::SAML2 only works correctly some types of request; IIRC when only the Assertion element is signed, not the whole Response, it was failing.  I was trying to fix that bug.  (I ended up commenting out all the signature checking in Net::SAML2 and using the xmlsec1 command to do that for my application.)